# Robocopy does not work properly when using system(), and in windows context menu

Tags: c++, contextmenu, robocopy

I'm trying to get this code to work, but when I use the context menu from the root directory of a drive, it makes `argv[3]` be `E:"`. I have no idea why there's a single quote.

When this happens, it creates a corrupted directory tree that is `E:\x\e\` (I assume the second `e` comes from `/E` argument for robocopy).

When it is not in the root directory of a drive, it takes the first piece of the directory it is copying to, up until a space, and then creates a second directory with the second half, which contains only the folders with no files being copied.

Here is my code:

```
std::ifstream file (dir + argv[2] + ".txt"); //this is where robocopy source is determined
std::string contents;
std::getline(file, contents);
file.close();

//the destination (argv[3] is equal to %w in context menu registry in directory\backcground)
std::string folderDir = argv[3] + contents.substr(contents.find_last_of('\\'));

std::string command = "robocopy.exe \"" + contents + "\" \"" + folderDir + "\" \"/E\"";
system(command.c_str());
```

**UPDATE:**

This is how to reproduce it (the E:") on Windows 11:

C++ code:

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::ofstream file("test.txt");
    file << argv[1];
    file.close();
}
```

Registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Directory\Background\shell\test\command

@Default = "C:\test.exe" "%w"
```

The `test` and `command` keys will have to be created.

Comment: No, those are quotes to surround each argument for robocopy.

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with the registration of the context menu item, not the code that is reacting to the context menu. The context menu is not correctly populating the `argv` array that your code receives. Did you try logging the contents of the `argv` array to verify that?

Comment: `argv` appears to be sending the information it has correctly but I also discovered something strange. What I have in the registry for the context menu is `"...path to exe..." "arg 1" "arg 2" "%w"`. When the %w is in quotes, folder paths with spaces work fine but the root drive becomes `E:"`. When the %w is not in quotes, the drive alone turns into `E:\ ` (without space after \\), but the paths with spaces stop after the first space, with each piece before and after spaces becoming separate arguments.
When I use cmd to output the `"%w"` to a file however, it works fine and outputs as `E:\`.

Comment: Can you show your actual registration of the context menu item in your Registry? Or at least a [mcve]? Also, which version of Windows are you using? I tested on Windows 7, and I'm having a hard time reproducing what you describe. When I try it, using `"%w"` provides the root drive as, ie, ```C:\``` as expected, not as `C:"` as you claim. I had to add the command to a few different Registry keys just to make the command appear for the root drive, though.

Comment: Here's how I could get the C:". (In windows 11)
C++ code:
```
#include <fstream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::ofstream file("test.txt");
    file << argv[1];
    file.close();
}
```
Registry:
```
HKCR\\Directory\\Background\\shell\\test\\command
Default value of command = "C:\\test.exe" "%w"
``` test and command keys will have to be created (so sorry for whatever formatting issues are in this comment, on on a mobile device right now.)

Comment: I added that info to your question (where it belonged, not in comments)